# lightning search input type is not displaying the expected result

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightninginput

I have search input box  on searching the account names in the input box it should display the list of account names but i am unable to see the result i inspected my code but don't see any issues.
Can you help  me what is the issue.

```
public with sharing class AccountController {
  
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> findAccounts(String searchKey){
        String key = '%' + searchKey + '%';
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Type, Industry FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :key LIMIT 5];
    }
}


Apexdemo.html

<template>
    <lightning-card title="Apex Wire To Property Demo">
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
            <lightning-input type="search" 
            label="Search Account" value={searchKey} 
            onchange={searchHandler}>

            </lightning-input>
        </div>
        <template if:true={accounts}>
            <template for:each={accounts} for:item="account">
                <div class="slds-box slds-box_xx-small" key={account.Id}>
                    <p>Name -{account.name}</p>
                    <p>Type -{account.Type}</p>
                    <p>Industry -{account.Industry}</p>
                </div>
            </template>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

Apexdemo.js file :

import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import findAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.findAccounts'
export default class ApexImperativeDemo extends LightningElement {
    searchKey=''
    accounts
    timer
    searchHandler(event){
        window.clearTimeout(this.timer)
        this.searchKey = event.target.value
        this.timer = setTimeout(()=>{
            this.callApex()
        }, 1000)
    }

    callApex(){
        findAccounts({searchKey:this.searchKey})
        .then(result=>{
            this.accounts = result
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.error(error)
        })
    }
}
```

[image: Output of the result]

Comment: try to console your result in js and `list<Account>` in your apex  controller. Also instead of writing just `accounts` use `@track accounts=[];` in your js file

Comment: @ShagunSharma I have used console.log in the below statment but don't see any values passed after searching in input filed under developer console console tab and used the track decorator    .then(result=>{
            this.accounts = result
            console.log(result)

Comment: I have run the SOQL from query editor could see that the results are being fetched correctly

Comment: I was able to see under object property and cleared the browser cache and  redeployed the code it worked                                                                               
      Object
apexImperativeDemo.js:4 
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {Id: "0015g00000FtsZDAAZ", Name: "Test for Account"}
1: {Id: "0015g00000FtsquAAB", Name: "Test"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code.It seems working for me .Only issue I found that it was not displaying account Name(as you are using account.name change it with account.Name).However it was displaying Type and Industry after I provided suitable searchKey.

Code

```
<div class="slds-box slds-box_xx-small" key={account.Id}>
                <p>Name -{account.Name}</p>
                <p>Type -{account.Type}</p>
                <p>Industry -{account.Industry}</p>
            </div>
```